# Good resource for creating a portal in aspx from design perspective

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to learn how to create a portal using asp and C#. I have learned language features of C# and asp. I want to learn how one should design a portal (like banking).

Regards,

Sachin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well probably the best start is the ASP.NET starter kits available at http://www.asp.net.

**Edit**

The link for the Starter Kits page is [here](http://www.asp.net/community/projects).

Brgds